# Problemas al tratar de envolver Gridview.Builder dentro de un Widget

Tags: flutter

Estoy mostrando imagenes como respuesta de una Api dentro de un Gridview.builder, al envolverlo dentro de un center todo va bien.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema surge cuando lo que pretendo es agregar un sizebox para alejar el gridview del
appbar y poner contenido en medio de ellos.
el center solo tiene child por lo cual no puedo poner mas elementos. pero quiero remplazarlo por un listview o un column que recibe childrens. y no me lanza ningun error por consola.
simplemente la app se queda en blanco.

Codigo del gridview

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Dogdata>>(
      future: fetchDogdata(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Dogdata>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final lista = snapshot.data!;
          return GridView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
              
            ),
            itemCount: lista.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  //border: Border.all(),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,

                ),
                child: Image.network(
                  lista[index].imagen,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: double.infinity,
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        } else {
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

y la pantalla principal que al ponerle el column o listview da error.

```
body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Api(),
            ],
          )),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es muy probable que sea tema de renderizado, te aconsejo que lo dejes tal como lo tienes, lo único que creo que te serviría es encerrar el `GridView.builder` en un exanded:

```
Scaffold(
 appbar: appbar(),
 body: Column(children: [
    //Widget entre el app y el gridView
    miWidget(),
    //GridView
    Expanded(
      child: Api(),
   )
  ]
 ),
),
```

`expanded` lo que hará es ocupar el resto del espacio que quede en pantalla, con eso creo que debería irse el problema de la pantalla en blanco.

Otra solución sería encerrar el GridView en un contenedor y darle una altura fija, pero no creo que busques eso.

Comment: muchas gracias bendiciones

Answer (score 1):

Quitar ese center. Deja solo el column y como hijos pon un sizebox con la altura deseada y después un expanded con el GridView